# How to Download entire Firebase RealtimeDatabase in CSV format with a click inside the app itself?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to download my App's databse as a CSV file on clicking a buttin from an activity. Please Help.

Comment: Sorry, but that is too broad a question. Both Android and Firebase have APIs with great documentation that allow you to implement this. I'd recommend starting by adding a button, and then by reading from the database. If you get stuck along the way, post a new question with the concrete problem and a [minimal complete verifiable example of where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference for Firebase Database on Android is here:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot

The process I would follow is 1) Get a reference to your database using `getRef()` and then 2) get the contents of the database with `getValue()`.  This will give you the contents of your database as native objects, so you will have to write your own parser to turn it into a CSV, and then save that as a file.